# Linking external C++ source to my DLL library

Tags: c, visual-c++, dll, visual-studio-2013, qr-code

I am currently implementing a DLL in visual c++ to generate a QRCode. To generate the QR code, i have downloaded the QRGenration source code from open source. The source code has the file "**QRGenerator.cpp**" which has the "**main**" function, which generates the QRCode. The QRGeneation source code compiles successfully and generates the QRCode when executed.

Now i want to make a call to QR Code generation function from my new DLL which i am implementing. In this case,

- I want to rename the function "main" in "QRGenerator.cpp" as "GenerateQRCode"
- And then call "GenerateQRCode" from my DLL.

I am currently unable to rename the main function name in "GenerateQRCode". When i change the main function to "GenerateQRCode" i get below error.

*>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup*

I am new to visual C++ and i am out of my options to make this compilation work. Can you please help me, how can i make a call to QR Generation function("GenerateQRCode") from my DLL.

P.S: For reference i am pasting below my directory structure of my program

c:\MYDLL\MyDLL.cpp

c:\QRGeneration\(Source code)

c:\QRGeneration\QRGeneration.cpp

Thanks in advance :).

**Solution**
I have created an existing project with type static library of  QRCode.I exported the function which generate the QRCode using extern in my library. I then linked this library in my DLL as mentioned in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx. And generated my DLL file.

The QRCode is generated when my DLL is called. 
Thanks :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just renamed main to another function in a MSVC project that is meant to generate an executable (.exe) file, then it will not work because main() will be missing.

You need to set up another project that creates a DLL, then set its options to be similar to the one that generates your QR executable, so that this DLL will use any sources and libraries that the original QR project uses, then rename main() in this one to GenerateQRCode.

You also need to export this function so when you load your new DLL from another exe or dll, this function will be visible and can be called. This can be done either by delaring it with __declspec(dllexport) or by using a .def file in your project in which you declare this export in the EXPORTS section.

A good idea is to export it, or a C wrapper using extern "C" so the executable that tries to use it will not need to be compiled with the same exact compiler that you compiled your DLL with (due to name mangling), but this depends on how you intend to use it.

EDIT:

According to your last update, you elected to create a static library that contains the QR code binaries, and then linked it with your DLL. Then you copied this DLL to another location and you generated a QR code by calling the entry point function. Your DLL now contains all necessary binaries from the QR static library, and is self-sufficient. 
Furthermore, since you moved the DLL to another location and it generates a QR code, it means no other external QR-related binary is used. 
To ensure this, download dependency walker from [here](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), run it, then drop your DLL in it, and see what other DLLs it depends on.

Note: the 'extern' keyword you mentioned, by itself does not export symbols. It merely declares that a symbol exists somewhere in your total code.

Comment: DNT :Thanks for your reply."You need to set up another project that creates a DLL, then set its options to be similar to the one ....".  How can we do this. I still didn't get an idea on how to link the QR source code to my DLL :(

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking how to use MS Visual Studio to set up a DLL project, or how to use source and lib files in a DLL project?

Comment: DNT: I have finally found a solution. I have created an static library project of QRCode and then linked this library to my DLL. It works fine. I still have one more doubt. I copied only the DLL file to a specific location(c:/Mypath/mydll.dll), which will be called by application. I only copied new DLL file into this path and didnot copy the QRGenerator library file. Still a call to my DLL generates the QRCode. Is my DLL generated with library ? I am interested in knowing how this works. Note:I have export the function "GenerateQRcode" using extern in QRCode library.